# Android only: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Tags: javascript, android, ios, ajax

I have a web application that makes a lot of ajax calls and opened up headers to allow cross domain.

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

I get this error in the console when I try to call on android devices.  When I test on apple devices and browsers, it works fine.

My initial guess is that despite it only happening in Android, it's still a certificate issue but wanted to get thoughts on why this is happenning on Android only and not iOS and desktop.